# Spring Repository Update - No property found for type

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have searched on StackOverflow a solution for this on the other discussions about this same error, but couldn't find an answer for this specific scenario.

Here is what's happening.

I have the following Spring Repository.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{   

       @Modifying
       @Query("update User u set u.userDesc = :userDesc where u.userName = :userName")
       public int updateUser(String userDesc, String userName);
}
```

Getting this error.

*Could not create query for public abstract int com.xyz.UserRepository.updateUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract int com.xyz.UserRepository.updateUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)! No property 'updateUser' found for type 'User';*

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not related, since the exception is from JPA and not JDBC, but you are using a class named `User` as your data class name and table name as I can see from the query. Depending on what underlying database you are using, you could be running into conflicts relating to **restricted** keywords of that database.

For example, in newer versions of H2 the `USER` keyword is restricted.
https://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html

On another note, if you run a clean SpringBoot project with the following:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class UserTest {
    
    public UserTest(){}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Long id;

    public String userDesc;

    public String userName;

}
```

---

```
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository< UserTest, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update UserTest u set u.userDesc = :userDesc where u.userName = :userName")
    public int updateUser(String userDesc, String userName);
}
```

It does run and the update method works just fine, so the issue must be somewhere else in your code, or in your imports which you are not showing.

Comment: No. The db table name is Users and the entity is User. @Entity @Table(name="users") public class User implements Serializable{...}. The update command should use the entity name, not the table name. So "@Query("update User..." should be ok. Anyways, I changed the table name to userstbl and the entity code to @Table(name="userstbl") and got the same error.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. I've tried spinning up a new SpringBoot project and doing what you did and it worked just fine, so the issue must be somewhere else that you're not showing in your question.

Comment: You got it! I was using the wrong imports. import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
Thank you. Just accepted the answer.